# SharePoint 2013 master page: unable to find in look n feel

Tags: master-page, custom-masterpage

I have uploaded my **HTML Master page** (a **customized Seattle maste**r page) to the Master page gallery. Then it automatically generated the `.master` file.

For some reason, the Master page is not appearing in the **look n feel** master page settings where you can specify which Master page you want to use.

I published the master page as can be seen below (iaof.master):

[image]

Is there any step I am missing here?

Comment: did you publish it?

Comment: Yes, I did publish it. Please see above.

Answer (score 2):

Follow below mentioned steps.

1. Inside the current site's **Site Settings**, navigate to **Site Collection Administration** > **Site Collection Features**.
2. Activate **SharePoint Server Publishing Infastructure** if it's available... if it's not, you may be using SharePoint Foundation.
3. Navigate to **Site Actions** > **Manage Site Features**, and activate the **SharePoint Server Publishing** feature.
4. Return to **Site Settings**. You will get **Look and Feel** & under it, "**Master page**" should now be available.

Comment: Hardik, thanks, however "master page" is available already. I just mean that My specific master page is now showing up in the master pages under look and feel.

Comment: Please check this link ....https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/03/27/stage-6-upload-and-apply-a-new-master-page-to-a-publishing-site/